# Removing random elements from ArrayList Java

Tags: random, arraylist, frequency

after a couple of hours of trying this by myself I figured I would ask for help.

This am trying to implement a multi set of character and provided certain operations such as add, remove, etc. Those all work well, but I am having trouble with this last method that is suppose to return a random character base on frequency. I am using an ArrayList to do everything and it has been going excellent all except this last part. So basically, if there are 50 z's and 50 e's in my multi set then they should have an equal chance of being outputted. If there are 4 a's and 2 b's a's should be outputted more. I tried to use the "frequency" method available from the Collections framework and I have the frequency of each character in a foreach loop, but do not know how to randomize appropriately. In addition I tried to use the Math.random and had the range be the characters in my ArrayList, but it did not turn out correctly.

If anyone could help me with this I would sincerely appreciate it. At this point I don't really know what else to try. Here is the complete class for my code. It's probably easier to share the whole file so you can see what I'm dealing with.

```
public class DenseMultiSetOfChar implements MultiSetOfChar{

    private ArrayList<Character> multi;

    public DenseMultiSetOfChar() {

        multi = new ArrayList<Character>();

    }

    public DenseMultiSetOfChar(char c) {

        multi = new ArrayList<Character>();

        multi.add(c);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCardinality() {

        return this.multi.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getElementCount(char target) {
        int cardinalityCount = 0;

        // relating get element count and get cardinality.
        // sum of get element count for each char is == to cardn
        // of the set.

        for(char wantedCh : this.multi)
        {
            if(wantedCh == target)
            {
                cardinalityCount++;
            }
        }

        return cardinalityCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Character> getElementSet() {

        Set<Character> withoutDuplicates = new HashSet<Character>();
        List<Character> copiedList = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(new Character[this.multi.size()]));

        Collections.copy(copiedList, this.multi);

        for(char ch : copiedList)
        {
             withoutDuplicates.add(ch);
        }


        return withoutDuplicates;


    }

    @Override
    public void add(char item) {
        if(this.multi.size() < Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        {
                multi.add(item);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(char target) {

        boolean result = false;


        if(this.multi.contains(target))
        {

            this.multi.remove(this.multi.indexOf(target));
            result = true;
        }

        return result;

    }

    @Override
    public char randomUniformChoose() {
        //does not remove or change cardinality.
        //char that appears n times in multset with
        //cardinatlity m, prob of that ch being returnd
        //is n/m

        char result;
        int count = 0;
        int probability = 0;
        int index = 0;
        int randNum = 0;
        List<Character> copiedList = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(new Character[this.multi.size()]));

        Collections.copy(copiedList, this.multi);

        Random rand = new Random();


        // use randomNum to remove based on index. If there are more
        // 50a's and 50'b, this it will give a fair opportunity of removing
        // either one.
        randNum = rand.nextInt(copiedList.size() - 0 +1) +0;
        for(char ch : copiedList)
        {
            count = Collections.frequency(copiedList, ch);


        }


        result = copiedList.remove(count);

        return result;
    }



}
```

Here is the test driver.

```
    public class TestDenseMultiSetOfCharSimple {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultiSetOfChar e = new DenseMultiSetOfChar();
        MultiSetOfChar s = new DenseMultiSetOfChar('a');

        System.out.println("Cardinality is " + s.getCardinality()
                + " (should be 1)");
        System.out.println("No. of a's is " + s.getElementCount('a')
                + " (should be 1)");
        System.out.println("No. of b's is " + s.getElementCount('b')
                + " (should be 0)");

        Set<Character> basis = s.getElementSet();
        System.out.println("Cardinality of basis set is " + basis.size()
                + " (should be 1)");

        s.add('a');
        s.add('a');
        s.add('b');

        System.out.println("Cardinality is " + s.getCardinality()
                + " (should be 4)");
        System.out.println("No. of a's is " + s.getElementCount('a')
                + " (should be 3)");
        System.out.println("No. of b's is " + s.getElementCount('b')
                + " (should be 1)");

        basis = s.getElementSet();
        System.out.println("Cardinality of basis set is " + basis.size()
                + " (should be 2)");

        boolean result = s.remove('c');
        System.out.println("Able to remove element c? " + result
                + " (should be false)");

        result = s.remove('a');
        System.out.println("Able to remove element a? " + result
                + " (should be true)");
        System.out.println("No. of a's is now " + s.getElementCount('a')
                + " (should be 2)");

        System.out
                .println("Random string (should have about twice as many a's as b's");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.print(s.randomUniformChoose());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go the strait forward method:

```
public char randomUniformChoose() {
    return this.multi.get((int)(Math.random() * this.multi.size()));
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if this is correct either. I am using a test driver in another class that does a for loop and calls the method randomUniformChoose 100 times and does a System.out.println and all I got was a's. What is currently in the multiset at execution time is: a, a, b.

Comment: That is odd, I just ran the same test and got: abaaaaaaaabbbaaaabbbaaabaaabaabaabaaaababbaaabbaaabaabaabaabaaababaabbabaaaaabbbaaaaababababaabaaaab.  Can you show me your implementation?

Comment: Sure, thanks for helping me. The class I posted above is the main implementation. I just went ahead and added the test driver.Yeah my original thought was this should be hard at all because if there are more occurrences of something in a set, those things will get printed out naturally.

Comment: Your test harness looks ok, did you use the `randomUniformChoose` from my answer or something different based off of it?

Comment: Okay, never mind. Wow, apparently something didn't output correctly. It does work. Thank you very much. I knew this wasn't that hard. Thank you again...